# Binary search code in java won't run

Tags: java, loops, compiler-errors, binary-search

I am quite new to coding so no hate. I am trying to code a binary search, however, for some reason my code doesn't work.

```
public class CodeSkillsCheck {

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */


int[] value = {5,10,15,20,25,30,35,40,45,50};
int length;

  public boolean binarySearch(int num)
  {
      int small = 0;
      int big = value.length;

      while(big >= small)
      {
          int mp = (small+big)/2;
          if(value[mp] < num)
          {
              big = mp - 1;
          } else {

              big = mp + 1;
          }
      }

      return false;
  } 


public static void main(String[] args) {

    System.out.println(binarySearch(46));

   }
}
```

What can I do in order to make it work? Thank you in advance!

Comment: For binary search your array should be sorted

Comment: What exactly does not work? You used the tag "compiler-errors", what error are you getting?

Comment: I get the following error: 'Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable source code - illegal start of expression' @QBrute

Comment: Well, you defined a method inside `main`. That doesn't work, it has to be outside of it.

Comment: Right, so that error message should be in your question. Next, don't try running code that doesn't compile - you shouldn't get as far as an exception.

Comment: It works now @QBrute Thank you

Comment: Your code has got many problems :
- First, you cannot declare a method inside a main.
- Second, you int[] value has no value in it, and you try to access the cell mp of the array, this cannot work.

Try to organise your code, and maybe explain us what you are trying to achieve

Comment: Hint: this is not programming school were we teach you syntax basics.

Comment: I put my method out of the main, added values to my array, but how would I print the binary search? Go to the main, and println? @L01c

Comment: Please update your post with the new code

Comment: The code is updated @L01c

Comment: You always return false, by the way.

Comment: You never change `small` - in your `if(value[mp] < num)` you need an `else` part which changes `small`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The aim of the binary search is to find the index of a number inside a sorted array in a complexity **log(n)**.

---

**FIRST STEP : initialization**

You start with your sorted array : {5,10,15,20,25,30,35,40,45,50}

**small** : is the current smallest index. At the beginning it should be 0 for a zero-based array.

**big** : is the current biggest index. At the beginning it should be the length of the array.

---

**SECOND STEP** : loop

while big >= small, you compute mid = (small + big) / 2.

- If the value you are looking for is the one at the index mid, then **you return true**.
- else if the value you are looking for is lower than the value at index mid, then you want to look a the lowest part of the array, so big becomes mid-1.
- **ELSE** **(and this is missing in your code)** small becomes mid+1, because you want now to look on the highest part of the array.

If you go out of the loop, meaning that big is smaller than small, then you haven't found the value, **you return false**.

---

**FINNALY** : you need to call the method binarySearch of a number inside your main method

Comment: I updated my code, is that what you mean?

Comment: Almost, you need to return true if you find the value.